# Analyzing data in order of column and then row in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a dataset of logged data at 5 minutes intervals that also includes data at 1 minute intervals denoted by _1 - _5 in the header.
Each row represents a 5 minute interval.

```
datetime            temp  speed_1  speed_2  speed_3  speed_4  speed_5
20190710 09:00:00   21    13       14       26       29       32
20190710 09:05:00   21    28       28       29       38       12
20190710 09:10:00   20    8        15       29       30       19
20190711 11:12:00   18    6        9        18       51       49
20190711 11:17:00   17    49       48       48       30       10
```

The actual dataset has an additional 25 columns of data logged at 5 minute intervals and consists of approximately 25000 rows.

I'm looking for an efficient way of analyzing the speed for each day.
For example, if I wanted to plot the speed for each day it would take speed_1 to speed_5 from the earliest entry on a particular day, say 09:00:00, then speed_1 to speed_5 from the next time, 09:05:00, and so on for the whole day.

Currently I have created an additional dataframe for the speed that fills in the times to give:

```
datetime            speed
20190710 09:00:00   13
20190710 09:01:00   14
20190710 09:02:00   26
20190710 09:03:00   29      
20190710 09:04:00   32
```

This results in having a second df of 125000 entries. I was wondering if there was a more memory efficient way of analyzing the original dataset as the datasets may grow considerably in the future.

Edit: Reproducible code added

`structure(list(time = structure(1:3, .Label = c("20190710 09-00-00", "20190710 09-05-00", "20190710 09-10-00"), class = "factor"), temp = c(21, 21, 20), speed_1 = c(13, 28, 8), speed_2 = c(14, 28, 15), speed_3 = c(26, 29, 29), speed_4 = c(29, 38, 30), speed_5 = c(32, 12, 19)), .Names = c("time", "temp", "speed_1", "speed_2", "speed_3", "speed_4", "speed_5"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make a reproducible example of the data. You can use `dput()` and paste the result in.

Comment: Nice, but you can actually edit the question. The reproducible example should go in the question, not in the comment. ;)

Comment: Added to the actual question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` version:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df <- read.table(text='datetime            temp  speed_1  speed_2  speed_3  speed_4  speed_5
"20190710 09:00:00"   21    13       14       26       29       32
"20190710 09:05:00"   21    28       28       29       38       12
"20190710 09:10:00"   20    8        15       29       30       19
"20190711 11:12:00"   18    6        9        18       51       49
"20190711 11:17:00"   17    49       48       48       30       10',header=T)

# we take our dataframe
df %>%
    # ...then we put all the speed columns in one column
    pivot_longer(starts_with("speed_")
                 , names_to = "minute"
                 , values_to = "speed") %>%
    # ...then we...
    mutate(datetime = ymd_hms(datetime) #...turn the "datetime" column actually into a datetime format
           , minute = gsub("speed_", "", minute) %>% as.numeric() # ...remove "speed_" from the former column names (which are now in column "speed")
           , datetime = datetime + minutes(minute - 1)) # ...and add the minute to our datetime...
```

...to get this:

```
# A tibble: 25 x 4
   datetime             temp minute speed
   <dttm>              <int>  <dbl> <int>
 1 2019-07-10 09:00:00    21      1    13
 2 2019-07-10 09:01:00    21      2    14
 3 2019-07-10 09:02:00    21      3    26
 4 2019-07-10 09:03:00    21      4    29
 5 2019-07-10 09:04:00    21      5    32
 6 2019-07-10 09:05:00    21      1    28
 7 2019-07-10 09:06:00    21      2    28
 8 2019-07-10 09:07:00    21      3    29
 9 2019-07-10 09:08:00    21      4    38
10 2019-07-10 09:09:00    21      5    12
# ... with 15 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Some example data and expected output would help a lot. I gave it a shot anyways. You can do this if you simply want a list of all the speeds for every date.

```
dataset <- read.table(text='datetime            temp  speed_1  speed_2  speed_3  speed_4  speed_5
"20190710 09:00:00"   21    13       14       26       29       32
"20190710 09:05:00"   21    28       28       29       38       12
"20190710 09:10:00"   20    8        15       29       30       19
"20190711 11:12:00"   18    6        9        18       51       49
"20190711 11:17:00"   17    49       48       48       30       10',header=T)


dataset$datetime <- as.POSIXlt(dataset$datetime,format="%Y%m%d %H:%M:%OS")

lapply(split(dataset,as.Date(dataset$datetime)), function(x) c(t(x[,3:ncol(x)])) )
```

output:

```
  $`2019-07-10`
 [1] 13 14 26 29 32 28 28 29 38 12  8 15 29 30 19

$`2019-07-11`
 [1]  6  9 18 51 49 49 48 48 30 10
```

Edit: Updated answer so that the speeds are in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something raw using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, time := as.POSIXct(time, format="%Y%m%d %H-%M-%OS")]
out <- 
  df[, !"temp"
   ][, melt(.SD, id.vars = "time")
     ][, time := time + (rleid(variable)-1)*60, time
       ][order(time), !"variable"]
out

#                    time value
#  1: 2019-07-10 09:00:00    13
#  2: 2019-07-10 09:01:00    14
#  3: 2019-07-10 09:02:00    26
#  4: 2019-07-10 09:03:00    29
#  5: 2019-07-10 09:04:00    32
#  6: 2019-07-10 09:05:00    28
#  7: 2019-07-10 09:06:00    28
#  8: 2019-07-10 09:07:00    29
#  9: 2019-07-10 09:08:00    38
# 10: 2019-07-10 09:09:00    12
# 11: 2019-07-10 09:10:00     8
# 12: 2019-07-10 09:11:00    15
# 13: 2019-07-10 09:12:00    29
# 14: 2019-07-10 09:13:00    30
# 15: 2019-07-10 09:14:00    19
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("20190710 09-00-00", "20190710 09-05-00", "20190710 09-10-00")),
  temp = c(21, 21, 20),
  speed_1 = c(13, 28, 8),
  speed_2 = c(14, 28, 15),
  speed_3 = c(26, 29, 29),
  speed_4 = c(29, 38, 30),
  speed_5 = c(32, 12, 19)
)
```